# how do I extract text from a webpage when the specific text is in a span tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to write a python program that runs through a google classroom page and extracts the text of any new posts my teacher writes. I have tried running many different suggested codes and none have worked for me. Every posts CSS is under the following tag:  "any text here" . Any attempt I have made to extract text has failed. My end goal is to write a program that will take all the text under any of these  tags and filter them to only return posts that contain specific keywords. The main issue is that when I try to extract the text, the program always returns an empty
array/[] despite that there is text there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should provide some more context for your question, as it's hard to help you without understanding what the CSS looks like, what you've tried so far, etc. Here's more info on how to write a good question on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:
Using stackoverflow.com, we can select the title in between two span tags.

```
import urllib.request
import re

fid=urllib.request.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/')
webpage=fid.read().decode('utf-8')
print(webpage + "\n") # print the contents of the webpage
title = re.findall("<title>(.*?)</title>", webpage) #copy the title in between the two span tags
print("The Title of the webpage is:\n")
print(title)
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6JIa.png)

```
import re
spantag = '<p><span style = "color:#8866ff;"> Hello World </span>'
all = re.findall("\;\"\>(.*?)</span>", spantag)
print(all)
```

[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPS61.png)